# Wordpress enqueue script in to a page template fails

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to enqueue a script into a specific page template, but it seems to just not load any of the scripts in the if statement, I've tried the is_page version and it does the same thing. If anyone can point out where I'm going wrong I'd be very grateful.

```
function di_load_javascript()  
{  
    // Deregister the included library  
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );  
    // Register the library again from Google's CDN  
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js', array(), null, false );  

    wp_register_script( 'jquery-masonry', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.masonry.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
    wp_register_script( 'blog-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/blog.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
    wp_register_script( 'home-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/home.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );

    // Enqueue the scripts for all pages
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' ); 

    // Enqueue the scripts for Home
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('home-scripts');
    };  
    // Enqueue the scripts for Blog (is_page_template fails for some reason)
    //if ( is_page(array(2,'blog','Blog')) ) {
    if ( is_page_template('templates/blog.php') ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-masonry');    
        wp_enqueue_script('blog-scripts');
    };
} 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'di_load_javascript' );
```

What's bizarre is the scripts load for the home page via is_front_page fine. I am very confused :(

Comment: Did you include `wp_head()` in your header.php?

Comment: Yep, it enqueues the jquery, and if I remove the if statements all of the scripts load

Comment: your version of wordpress is 3.4 ? the sub directory only works in 3.4+

Comment: It enqueues home-scripts and jquery, is that what you're saying? Because what's different with them compared to the others is the others are to be included through the footer (fifth parameter is true). Are you calling wp_footer?

Comment: Nope, latest build (Version 3.4.2)

But the home scripts load in the footer on the home page too, maybe i should load the files in the template file rather than the functions file?

Comment: @calle 
If i amend the code to move wp_enqueue_script ( 'blog-scripts' ); etc to underneath the jquery, it loads the scripts fine, just on every page (this is an option but wanted to optimise it so these files dont load on every page)

Comment: OK, sorry I misread. The next thing I would do to find out what's wrong is echo get_page_template_slug( get_queried_object_id() ) because this is what is_page_template compares with.

Comment: If you are using PHP ver. > 5.3 you could do add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() { echo 'Template: ' . get_page_template_slug( get_queried_object_id() ); exit; } ); to see exactly what is_page_template works with.

Comment: Sounds like a good way to go, how do I go about implementing that, would i just replace my add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'di_load_javascript' ); with the one you just pasted, test it and it will output the template name?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18473/discussion-between-calle-and-jamie)

Comment: Did you place your blog.php template inside a 'templates' subfolder? did you double check that your page is using this template? An easy way to verify you are checking for the correct template, is to use [get_page_template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_template) this on the page and make sure it's the same name.

Answer (score 0):

This below code works perfectly.

```
      function my_enqueue_stuff() {

 // "page-templates/about.php" is the path of the template file. If your template file is in Theme's root folder, then use it as "about.php".

        if(is_page_template( 'page-templates/about.php' ))
        {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'lightgallery-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lightgallery-all.min.js');
            wp_enqueue_script('raventours-picturefill', "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/picturefill/2.3.1/picturefill.min.js", true, null);
        }
        }
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_stuff' );
```